# AJAX Form Submit With Enter

Tags: php, ajax

When a user hits the button, everything works fine. But when they hit enter, the page just reloads. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fun!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" media="print" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: arial;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function get() {
            $.post('data.php', { name: form.name.value }, 
                function(output) {
                    $('#age').html(output).show();
                }
            );
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="" name="form" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" /> <input type="button" value="Get" onClick="get();" />
        </form><br />

        <div id="age" style="display: none;">Result</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the `onclick` event for the button, this will not work when Enter is pressed, because it is not a click.

Take off `onclick` and add

```
onsubmit="event.preventDefault();get();return false;"
```

to the `<form>`.

`event.preventDefault();` `prevent`s the submission of the form (the `Default` action).

`return false;` is for older versions of Internet Explorer, because they don't support `e.preventDefault();`. Modern browsers ignore `return false;`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still just reloads the page.

`<form action="" name="form" method="post" onsubmit="get();">
    <input type="text" name="name" /> <input type="submit" value="Get" />
   </form><br />`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Use `onsubmit="event.preventDefault();get();"`. `preventDefault();` prevents the default action which is to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

When a user presses enter, the form will be submitted. You'll have to look for the `onsubmit` event of the form, rather than using the `onclick` event of the button.

```
<form ... onsubmit="get();">
    ...
</form>
```

Now you also have to prevent that the page actually submits (because you did it with AJAX). Add `return false;` at the end of the function `get()`.

It is better practice to assign the event using jQuery (since you are using it anyway), with the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still just reloads the page.

`<form action="" name="form" method="post" onsubmit="get();">
    <input type="text" name="name" /> <input type="submit" value="Get" />
   </form><br />`

Am I missing something?

Comment: @user1453094 You have to prevent the real page refresh (submit) by returning false in the function get().